# Hide a div partially from visible to invisible with smooth effect

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, next.js13

I am using Next js app to build a testimonial section. Everything else is build. I just want to make the outer cards partially invisible just like shown in the picture below. Any ideas on how to achieve this.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0m26.jpg)

I have googled for various options, used ChatGpt but nothing came to my mind
This is the HTML and tailwind section to view the cards.

```
<div className='flex flex-row justify-start gap-x-[20px] overflow-x-auto no-scrollbar pointer-events-none max-w-6xl w-full' ref={containerRef}>
                {testimonialData.map((testimonial, index) => (
                    <div className={`relative flex flex-col max-w-[32%] min-w-[32%]`} id={`testimonial-${index}`}>
                        <div className='testimonials-bg h-[220px] absolute top-0 w-full'></div>
                        <div key={index} className="p-[20px] testimonials-border h-[220px] relative">
                            <p className="text-white text-sm mb-[20px]">{testimonial.message}</p>
                            <div className='absolute bottom-[20px] left-[20px] flex flex-row justify-start gap-x-[10px] items-center'>
                                <div className='flex w-[48px] h-[48px] rounded-full justify-center items-center bg-[#D26783] text-white'>
                                    {testimonial.iconText}
                                </div>
                                <p className="text-white text-sm font-medium">{testimonial.customerName}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
```

Comment: What HTML (*not* JSX, the HTML that Next produces) and CSS have you created so far?

Comment: HI David,
Thanks for reaching out. I have edited the question and added the HTML. The cards are showing fine. Slider is working. I just want the outer cards to be going transparent as shown in the screen shot.

Comment: Okay, thanks; but we don't have your data so posting the JSX (or the Next template, or whatever) is of no actual use. What's the representative HTML, where's your (attempted) CSS? What's not working, what's happening instead?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the requirement. I have three divs. And I want the outer divs to be invisible from sides showing the background. I have used overflow hidden property but that just makes it immediate. I want a smooth effect.
Apologies if I am unable to explain it better.

Comment: The website can be seen at traveljinni.com. There is only one page currently. You can see the current progress under Testimonials section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using psuedo elements to place boxes over the ends of the flex-row. Once the left and right cards are obscured, use a CSS gradient to fade the borders into the background color.

```
.column-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.column-wrap:before {
  content: ' ';
  background: rgb(44,27,45);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(44,27,45,0.5) 0%, rgba(44,27,45,0) 35%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.column-wrap:after {
  content: ' ';
  background: rgb(44,27,45);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(44,27,45,0.5) 0%, rgba(44,27,45,0) 35%);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzztX.jpg

Comment: Glad to help. If you feel that the code snippet solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.